# Problema al imprimir columnas de una tabla hacia la derecha al recorrer un array en php

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, php7

Hice una tabla de semestres en la cual recorro un array que me imprime en un mismo campo los siguientes datos codigo, materia y calificacion, lo que hace es mostrar todas la materias que contiene cada semestre, no tengo problema para mostrar los datos, el problema esta en que me imprime cada semestre debajo del otro y la idea es que se imprima cada columna hacia la derecha como se aprecia en las siguientes imagenes.

Comment: Me confunde un poco tu codigo, porque la consulta parece ser de MySQL pero utilizas funciones de SQL Server, ¿te funciona de esa forma? (lejos de que te de el resultado que esperas). Saludos.

Comment: si me funciona, me he guidao del manual de php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi sugerencia es crear un arreglo por semestre y materias, donde hay la posibilidad de que no todos los semestres tengan la misma cantidad de materias, quedando algo así:

```
$datos = [
    [semestre1] = [
        [codigo1, materia1, calificacion1],
        [codigo2, materia2, calificacion2],
        [codigoX, materiaX, calificacionX],
    ],
    [semestre2] = [
        [codigo1, materia1, calificacion1],
        [codigoX, materiaX, calificacionX],
        // Este dejará una celda vacía
    ],
];
```

**Nota:** Estoy usando una notación poco común para realizar "evaluaciones sin if"; al principio puede resultar confuso, pero es realmente fácil, solo se pueden incluir sentencias o funciones que pueden ser evaluadas (isset(), is_array(), var == valor, etc.), generalmente se usa con una evaluación al final.

Por ejemplo:

```
// Este if
if(!isset($datos[$row['Semestre'])) {
    $datos[$row['Semestre'] = [];
}
// Hace lo mismo que la siguiente línea
// donde se ejecuta cada sentencia hasta que una devuelva falso
// o se llegue al final
(!isset($datos[$row['Semestre']) && $datos[$row['Semestre']] = []);
```

Si no te gusta o tu IDE te da error de sintaxis, simplemente conviértelo a "if normal".

Ahora sí, vamos con el código, se recorren los resultados de la consulta para agregarlos al arreglo:

```
// Inicializar arreglo
$datos = [];
// Saber cuál es el máximo de filas a mostrar
$max = 0;
// Recorrer todos los resultados
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    // Si no existe el semestre en el arreglo, crearlo
    (!isset($datos[$row['Semestre']) && $datos[$row['Semestre']] = []);
    // Agregar materia, cada materia será una fila en la tabla
    $datos[$row['Semestre']][] = [
        $row['Codigo'],
        $row['Materia'],
        $row['Calificacion']
    ];
    // Actualizar máximo de materias si es necesario
    ($max < count($datos[$row['Semestre']) && $max = count($datos[$row['Semestre']));
}

// Ya que está listo el arreglo, hay que crear la tabla
?>
        <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
<?php
// Imprimir encabezado de todos los semestres
foreach($datos as $semestre => $materias) {
    // Aquí no se hace nada con $materias, solo son los encabezados
    echo "<th>SEMESTRE $semestre</th>";
}
?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
// Ciclo para crear filas, de acuerdo al máximo obtenido
for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    // Primero se crea la fila
    echo "<tr>";
    // Recorrer semestres para buscar materias
    foreach($datos as $semestre => $materias) {
        echo "<td>";
        // Mostrar solo si existe la materia
        if(isset($datos[$semestre][$i])) {
            // Para incluir elementos de arreglo, enciérralos entre llaves
            echo "{$datos[$semestre][$i][0]}<br>{$datos[$semestre][$i][1]}<br>{$datos[$semestre][$i][2]}";
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: he probado el código, si me funiono para mostrar los semestres al lado del otro, pero me marca el siguiente error: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pruebaReserva\vistas\mapa.php on line 94

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pruebaReserva\vistas\mapa.php on line 94

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pruebaReserva\vistas\mapa.php on line 94  
Array
Array
Array y esa linea 94 es donde se encuentra esto: echo "{$materias[0]}<br>{$materias[1]}<br>{$materias[2]}";

Comment: aun no me funciona, no he logrado descubrir por que pasa eso

Comment: ya edite la pregunta agregue lo que pidio , var_dump($datos); donde lo debo poner exactamente?

Comment: Antes de comenzar a crear la tabla

Comment: @LULU, en la actualización de la pregunta no modificaste el segundo for, probablemente por eso sigues teniendo el problema.

Comment: gracias ya me funciono, me di cuenta que si era el for ya que no lo modifique bien y el echo no estaba bien

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo mal la tabla html, seria algo asi (si mi memoria no me falla jajaja)

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th><?php  echo "SEMESTRE ".$row['Semestre'];?></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['Codigo']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['Materia']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['Calificacion']; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Deberías adaptar la tabla a tu codigo pero por ahi viene el problema!